# How to store images of WordPress on Picasa or other image hosting sites?

Tags: wordpress, images

What is the best way to start a photo blog with WordPress, so that images are stored in Picasa, by image I mean image in **all sizes**, **thumbnails**, **featured images** and so on.

The problem is that there is a big limitation with space in host, I don't want to store images there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a CDN network such as Rackspace or Amazon, storing images on these types of networks are super fast since your images will be mirrored all over the globe and ultimately improve your page load time which in turn improves your SEO.

CDN networks are pay as you go and cost very little to run and they are super easy to use... just like dropbox if you used that before, or you can even download plugins for WordPress / Joomla / Drupal which integrate direct upload options.

CDN networks don't have send limits, or storage limits since you pay for your usage. Rackspace for example charge around 12p per a GB per a month for storage and less for sending. Worth considering if you want your site super fast.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **image hosting that allows hot-linking**.

[This article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-image-hosting-services/) mentions ImageShack, AllYouCanUpload and PhotoBucket. I have used PhotoBucket latter which works and very easy to use. I know both PhotoBucket and ImageShack are extensively use by image-heavy websites. You can also use [imgius](http://imgius.com/) that seems pretty slick.

Comment: Not exactly. There must be some extra features in blogger too (which I think there is not any by now)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Picasa, use Mediafire.

[Mediafire](http://mediafire.com) provides the facility of image hosting for free upto 50 GB. you can easily upload images in Mediafire with the use of its inbuilt plugin and display it on your WordPress blog.

Comment: My biggest problem is featured images in wordpress, how can I add featured images from outside of wordpress for posts?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy mediafire provide tools also

Comment: So, what plugin (or tools) I can use?